# How to check for and list all files created and modified on the C:/ drive when an executable is run

Tags: python, windows, cmd, exe

I am testing several .exe files that were made a long time ago by one of our Dev groups but no documentation remains for. I am wondering if a solution is already available or how I might tackle this solution in python. I honestly don't know where I would even start.

Comment: First thing that comes to mind is get a time when the file kicks off `startTime`. Then walk the directory of interest using `os.walk`. For each file, grab date created/modified https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237079/how-to-get-file-creation-modification-date-times-in-python and compare it with `startTime`. If it occurred later than the program started, you could assume the program created/modified it.

Comment: I think what you are asking for is slightly different than what Cyber mentions above. You want to know any and all files created and modified **by** a given exe, right?

Comment: You should be able to script the usage of [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) (i.e. set up specific process filter and send output to a file). If you felt *really* adventurous, you could reverse engineer the interface of the driver it uses and talk to that directly from your Python program.

Comment: Cyber's method did come to mind but its not necessarily efficient nor exact. sabhiram has the right idea. Andrew I will test that method later on and report back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are trying to do is attempt to map any and all files touched by a given exe. The reason this is not trivial, is because you can have numerous processes running on your system whaling away on your file-system.

Check out this python module called [pywatch](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pywatch). It is like the linux files-system watcher, where you can specify actions to do when files change in a folder you have the watcher "observe."

This problem becomes trivial if you either know a sub-dir in which all these exe's might operate on. In this case, just run one exe at a time with your watcher running and you should have a list fairly quickly.

If you really had to figure out roughly which files are being used by said exe's, then another thing you could do would be to measure files which are commonly being edited by the system when none of your exe's are running. Then build a blacklist out of that. Repeat with your exe running and compare lists.

Comment: sabhiram, this is a really good suggestion. I do have the potential directories narrowed down as opposed to the entire drive.  Ill try this out and report back.